# Existence of the set $\{\omega, \omega^\omega,...\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is the following a set?:

$\{\omega, \omega^{\omega},\omega^{{\omega}^{\omega}},\dots\}$.

$\omega$ here represents the set of all natural numbers, granted by the axiom of ZFC that gives us the existence of an inductive set.

Comment: I believe it depends on the value of $\omega$. When it is 1 then it's definitely not a set.

Comment: Hi Vim. I am sorry for being unclear. $\omega$ in my post represents the set of natural numbers. I'll make the change now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you believe that $f(0)=\omega$ is a set? Do you believe that 
$f(n+1)=\omega^{f(n)}$ is a set for each $n\in\omega$?

If you believe both of those things, then you believe that
$\{f(n):n\in\omega\}=\{\omega,\omega^\omega,\omega^{\omega^\omega},\dots\}$ is 
a set due to the Axiom of Replacement.

Comment: After looking at this again, I believe you meant $f(n+1) = \omega^{f(n)}$.

Comment: @Nectric: You right.

Answer (score 0):

Use the axiom of replacement.  Define a function from naturals to a stack of $\omega$s, so given that the naturals are a set (axiom of infinity) this is a set as well.